# Provencal word for "petit repas que les moissonneurs font vers 10 heures du matin"

Tags: lexique, provençal

The *A Glossary of Tudor and Stuart Words* by Walter W. Skeat (1914; available on [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/glossaryoftudors00skea)) contains an entry for *bever* ("a short intermediate repast") that also mentions a related word in Modern Provencal. Unfortunately, in the scanned version of the dictionary on Archive.org, that Provencal word is not very readable. See the image below.

[image]

I assume that the word is either "grandbéure" or "grand-béure". "Béure" is listed in the [lexique provençal](http://lexiqueprovencal.com/index.php5?page=lexique) but the word I'm looking for is not. I don't have access to the *Glossaire* cited in the entry (it isn't even listed in Skeat's list of references), so I'm hoping that someone on this site can confirm what the word is (with or without a hyphen).

Comment: Note: I don't have enough reps to create the tag 'provençal', which would be appropriate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is commonly an hyphen in ***grand-béure*** or, rarely, just a separation ***grand béure*** but it is never a compound single word.

It is pronounced in Provencal like "*grang béouré*" [gʁɑ̃ŋ bewʁe].

Frédéric Mistral - *Mirèio, 1859*

[image]

It translates in French to *grand-boire*:

[image]

Alphonse Daudet - *Numa Roumestan, 1881*

> — Remettez-vous, monsieur, madame… vous allez faire le grand-boire avec nous.
>
> Le Grand-boire, c’est le goûter des paysans provençaux. Il se sert en pleins champs, au lieu même du travail, sous un arbre quand on en trouve, dans l’ombre d’une meule, au creux d’un fossé.

Answer (score 2):

It would definitly be "grand-béure", based on "petit-déjeuner", even if hyphen depends on the use : "grand-mère" but "grand'place" (especially in northern France). However, as far as I know, hyphen is usual in provençal to create compound words : gasto-cire (slow preaching priest ), gasto-braio (unskilled tailor), gau-galin (poppy), Rèire-goust (aftertaste) etc